# Multiple access levels in CodeIgniter using SSL

Tags: apache, codeigniter, security, https, ssl-certificate

We are developing an application using CodeIgniter that has multiple levels of access(admin,employee,user). We want to manage this with SSL by giving each kind of user a special private key (certificate key) that will be used for authentication.

This is how our views are organized in folders:

views   >

```
   secure > 
           admin >
           employee >
           user >
```

This is part of our server configuration file where we secure these folders:

` 
                Allow from all

```
    <Directory /home/snivan/bustickets/application/views/secure/admin>
            SSLCACertificateFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/xcacertnew.pem
            SSLVerifyClient require
```

DocumentRoot /home/snivan/bustickets

```
    SSLEngine On
    ServerName xxxx
    SSLCertificateFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/server-cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/server-private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/gr_snivan_ca_server_chain.p$
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

    <Directory /home/snivan/bustickets>
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/snivan/bustickets/application/views/secure/admin>
            SSLCACertificateFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/xcacertnew.pem
            SSLVerifyClient require
            SSLVerifyDepth 3
            SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"xxxx$
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/snivan/bustickets/application/views/secure/employee>
            SSLCACertificateFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/xcacertnew.pem
            SSLVerifyClient require
            SSLVerifyDepth 3
            SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"xxxx$
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/snivan/bustickets/application/views/secure/user>
            SSLCACertificateFile /home/snivan/ca/servercerts/xcacertnew.pem
            SSLVerifyClient require
            SSLVerifyDepth 3
            SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"xxxx$
    </Directory>`
```

Direct access to https://dom.com/application/views/secure/admin/index.html is forbidden,
 but we can still access the views in this folder using the controller.

**How can we make each view accessed by the controller ask for a certificate, and is that possible at all ?**